# Error for convert command in command line

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a bash shell script as below.

```
#!/bin/bash

SIZES=("512" "1024" "2048")

for i in ${!SIZES[*]}
do
    SIZE=${SIZES[$i]}
    echo $SIZE

    # first, resize original image
    convert -resize $SIZE"x"$SIZE! chernarus2048.jpg chernarus$SIZE"x"$SIZE.jpg
    mkdir tiles$SIZE
    # slice resized image into 256x256 tiles
    convert -crop 256x256 chernarus$SIZE"x"$SIZE.jpg tiles$SIZE/tile%04d.jpg
    rm chernarus$SIZE"x"$SIZE.jpg
done
```

But when I run this in command line using the following command

```
sh generate_tiles.sh chernarus2048.jpg
```

I'm getting an error **convert: command not found**

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.2.The image is kept in the same folder where the shell script is placed. Please help me out.

Comment: Sounds like `convert` isn't in your path. Can you run it normally? What does `which convert` tell you?

Comment: Why are you giving an argument to your script? It doesn't use `$1` anywhere.

Comment: You could just write `for SIZE in ${SIZES[*]}`, you don't need to use `$i`.

Comment: try to add `echo` before the `convert` command, to see exactly how this command is evaluated. Also, use quotes around variables! `"$SIZE"`, etc.

Comment: @Tom Fenech 'which convert' does not give anything in terminal

Comment: @Tom Fenech Please help me to set 'convert' in my path

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your suggestions.But my basic problem is with 'convert' command.

Comment: Are you sure you even have a `convert` command? I don't think it's a normal OS X command.

Comment: @Barmar  As far as I know 'convert' command  is  a part of ImageMagick library.

Comment: Thanks all for your support

Comment: Don't run a bash script with `sh`. Even though OSX's `sh` happens to be bash, it behaves differently, and some bash features are disabled.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Steps to follow

- Confirm **macport** is installed for reference
  https://www.macports.org/install.php
- Then install imagemagick using any of the following method

**install using command`$ sudo port install ImageMagick` 
or using Homebrew command `brew install imagemagick` 
or download from the link http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/**

- Then close your terminal and restart the pc and run your code again.

Comment: Yes, your links helped me. For my **Mac OS X Yosemite**, I downloaded the installer pkg for Yosemite from the list [here](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/)  and installed then ran the following code in my Mac Terminal > $ sudo port install ImageMagick

Answer (score 49):

You can also make it with help of [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) - which is quite nice and popular package manager

1. To Install homeBrew past in your terminal

   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
2. To install imagemagick past in the terminal

   brew install imagemagick

Comment: I had to use `brew install php56-imagick` (using homebrew-php, php 5.6 install)

Answer (score 7):

`convert` is part of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) which is not installed by default on OS X.

From the [download instructions](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) on the ImageMagick site:

- Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org)
- Install ImageMagick with

  ```
   $ sudo port install ImageMagick
  ```

Comment: @Matteo I installed MacPorts.But when I tried " $ sudo port install ImageMagick " it's giving an error "command not found".

Comment: @NevinRaj How did you install macports? Did you either re-source .bashrc? Did you open a new shell after the installation?

Comment: @Matteo  http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/   This link helped me to install ImageMagick. Still the error was persisting. Then I restarted my PC and opened a new terminal and then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

port install not work for me.
it always return "Error: Port ImageMagick not found"
if you failed installing with port, you can download pkg and install it directly from http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/