# Error 'convert: command not found' when using exec(convert ) in PHP script

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have installed my development server on my mac

```
Catalina 10.15.4
Apache (homebrew) => 2.4.43
PHP (homebrew) => 7.2.29
MySQL => 5.7.28

Imagemagick (homebrew) => 7.0.10
Imagick (homebrew) => 3.4.4
```

All Works perfectly! Except when i use `imagemagick` on a php script:

```
exec('convert -version', $debug, $return);
```

I get the error:

```
sh: convert: command not found
```

But when I do it on the mac Terminal, `convert -version`, it works! I get:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-0 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-04 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
```

I’ve read the following post and wasn’t able to fix it

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627473/error-for-convert-command-in-command-line
```

I did the following on the mac Terminal : `which convert` and I get :

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

My path looks like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I open my phpinfo, I see the imagick, but not imagemagick, like so

[image: phpinfo]

At this point, I’m not sure what is the problem. Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: The directory where `convert` is installed isn't in the search path of the webserver. Try using an absolute pathname.

Comment: @barmar I don't understand. The `PATH=` says `:/usr/local/bin` Isn't that the directory? Where should I use an `absolute pathname`?

Comment: @barmar oh! I just got it: I should use `exec('/usr/local/bin/convert -version', $debug, $return);` The funny thing is before a Mac, I was using a Windows machine for almost 20 years and I don't ever remember using an absolute path before the command `convert`. Thanks, all works perfectly!

Comment: The Windows machine probably has a system-wide search path.

Comment: Add the full path to convert in the exec command. And preface it with bash. `exec('bash /usr/local/bin/convert -version', $debug, $return);` Is ImageMagick installed with Imagick?

Answer (score 0):

Use `/usr/bin/magick` instead.

`convert` is deprecated in v7+ if I am not mistaken.